# Unable to load single-activity app into either my own device or an emulator

Tags: android

I'm trying to get into developing android apps but I'm unable to make this simple one-activity app work. I've been trying for several days, I've even rewritten the whole app, and I'm still clueless about why it gives me these errors. I've tried different ways of approaching the searching part but none of them gave me any helpful answer.

Right now I'm using a tablet to load the app into. I know it's well configured because if I load a hello world app it works fine. I'm using IntelliJ Idea, although I've tried with Eclipse too with the same results. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 using the IDE as root (Idea as root and Eclipse as my user, so I don't think that has anything to do with it, but it might be worthwhile to mention). I've run this with an emulator on eclipse but it didn't work either.

The app is a simple Dice generator, with 2 buttons, 2 textfields and a textview that fills the rest of the screen. Any kind of help would be highly appreciated. I hope I didn't overload my post, sorry if that's the case.

Run terminal output:

> Launching application: com.bluehouse.Dices/com.bluehouse.Dices.DiceGen.
>   DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -n "com.bluehouse.Dices/com.bluehouse.Dices.DiceGen" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
>   Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.bluehouse.Dices/.DiceGen }

Logcat output:

```
10-16 18:13:23.704    5005-5005/com.bluehouse.Dices E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.bluehouse.Dices/com.bluehouse.Dices.DiceGen}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:132)
at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:65)
at android.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:142)
at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.<init>(AlertDialog.java:359)
at com.bluehouse.Dices.DiceGen.<init>(DiceGen.java:186)
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-16 18:13:26.294    5005-5005/com.bluehouse.Dices I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 5005 SIG: 9
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.bluehouse.Dices"
  android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4"/>
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
    <activity android:name="DiceGen"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Code:

```
public class DiceGen extends Activity {

EditText dicesEditText, sidesEditText;
Button saveButton, genButton;
TextView resTextView;
int nsides,ndices, tempns,tempnd;
int testigo1 = 0, testigo2 = 0;

/*parentlist is a list array of DiceList objects.
Each DiceList object holds an array of Dice(s) with the same number of sides.*/
List<DiceList> parentlist = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    dicesEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dicesEditText);
    sidesEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sidesEditText);
    saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
    genButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.genButton);
    resTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resTextView);
}

TextWatcher sidesTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        try {
            tempns = Integer.parseInt(sidesEditText.getText().toString());

            if (nsides <= 0) {
                errorm.show();
            } else {
                nsides = tempns;
                testigo1 = 1;
            }
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e){
            errorm.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

    }

};

TextWatcher dicesTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        try {
            tempnd = Integer.parseInt(dicesEditText.getText().toString());

            if (ndices <= 0) {
                errorm.show();
            } else {
                ndices = tempnd;
                testigo2 = 1;
            }
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e){
            errorm.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

    }

};

public void genDices(View saveButton) {
    DiceList dicelist;
    Dice dice;

    if (testigo1 == 0 || testigo2 == 0) {
        terror.show();
    } else {
        /*If the list is empty, there is no need to check if
         there is already a DiceList holding that same kind of dice*/
        if (parentlist.isEmpty()) {
            dicelist = new DiceList(nsides);
            dicelist.setAmount(ndices);
            parentlist.add(dicelist);
            for (int i = 0; i < ndices; i++) {
                dice = new Dice(nsides);
                dicelist.insert(dice.getResult());
            }
        } else {

            /*If dices have been rolled, check for a DiceList with
             the same kind of dice the input has*/

            int parentindex = 0;
            DiceList dicelistindex;
            Boolean found = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < parentlist.size(); i++) {
                dicelistindex = parentlist.get(i);
                parentindex = dicelistindex.getType();

                /*If a match is found, insert dice result one by one there, if it's not,
                 create a new DiceList with the new value*/

                if (parentindex == nsides) {
                    found = true;
                    for (i = 0; i < ndices; i++) {
                        dice = new Dice(nsides);
                        dicelistindex.insert(dice.getResult());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!found) {
                dicelist = new DiceList(nsides);
                dicelist.setAmount(ndices);
                parentlist.add(dicelist);
                for (int i = 0; i < ndices; i++) {
                    dice = new Dice(nsides);
                    dicelist.insert(dice.getResult());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public void printDices(View genButton){
    if (!parentlist.isEmpty()){

        String todisplay="";
        DiceList parentindex;

        for (int i=0;i<parentlist.size();i++){
            parentindex = parentlist.get(i);
            todisplay = parentindex.getName()+parentindex.print();
        }
        resTextView.setText(todisplay);
        parentlist.clear();
    }
}

Builder errorm = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("oops")
        .setMessage(getString(R.string.errorm_body))
        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }});

Builder terror = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("oops")
        .setMessage(getString(R.string.terror_body))
        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }});
```

}

Comment: Please post your manifest file as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving below code

```
Builder errorm = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("oops")
        .setMessage(getString(R.string.errorm_body))
        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }});

Builder terror = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("oops")
        .setMessage(getString(R.string.terror_body))
        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }});
```

inside some function like this

```
public void showErrorm()
{
    Builder errorm = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("oops")
            .setMessage(getString(R.string.errorm_body))
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }});
}

public void showErrort()
{
    Builder terror = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("oops")
            .setMessage(getString(R.string.terror_body))
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }});

}
```

Later you can call this functions wherever u need.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked; tested it yesterday before leaving and it launched. It crashed later but I'll find the solution myself. Could you give me some insight there? I understand it had something to do with them not being inside a function, but I didn't read that anywhere in the official tutorials/documentation, so I don't really know why. Anyway, I can't vote you because I don't have enough reputation, but your answer did indeed help me so at least I marked it as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

### Maybe adding a period to your activity's name could fix the problem.

```
<activity android:name=".DiceGen"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
```

---

#### Or change this,

```
int testigo1 = 0, testigo2 = 0;

/*parentlist is a list array of DiceList objects.
Each DiceList object holds an array of Dice(s) with the same number of sides.*/
List<DiceList> parentlist = null;
```

#### To this.

```
int testigo1, testigo2;

/*parentlist is a list array of DiceList objects.
Each DiceList object holds an array of Dice(s) with the same number of sides.*/
List<DiceList> parentlist;
```

---

I get a lot of times this error, when i initialize Arrays and a lot of variables outside a method.
 Also, there is no need to define an instance variable with it's default value.

For example Integers have a default value of 0 and reference types like your ArrayList have a default value of "null".Thay's why I removed the initializations and I didn't define any variable

Comment: Thanks! I'm not so used to move between languages so I always mix something up. That "dot dotation" was the original answer by Ankhil and didn't work out, but his actual solution did it for me. Anyway, I can't vote you positively because I don't have enough reputation, sorry.